# Oracle Query Prevent Displayed Duplicate Record

Tags: oracle

Let's say i have a table structure like this :

```
ID   |    Name   |     SCHOOLNAME     |    CODESCHOOL
 1        DARK      Kindergarten 123           1
 2        DARK      Kindergarten 111           1
 3       Knight       NY University            3
 4       Knight       LA Senior HS             2
 5        JOHN          HARVARD                3
```

so, how to diplay all of the data above into like this :

```
ID   |    Name   |     SCHOOLNAME     |    CODESCHOOL
 1        DARK      Kindergarten 123           1
 3       Knight       NY University            3
 5        JOHN          HARVARD                3
```

my purpose is want to display data with the max of codeschool, but when i tried with my query below :

`SELECT NAME, SCHOOLNAME, MAX(CODESCHOOL) FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME, SCHOOLNAME`

but the result is just like this :

```
ID   |    Name   |     SCHOOLNAME     |    CODESCHOOL
 1        DARK      Kindergarten 123           1
 2        DARK      Kindergarten 111           1
 3       Knight       NY University            3
 4       Knight       LA Senior HS             2
 5        JOHN          HARVARD                3
```

maybe it caused by the `GROUP BY SCHOOLNAME`, when i tried to not select `SCHOOLNAME`, the data displayed just like what i expected, but i need the `SCHOOLNAME` field for search condition in my query

hope you guys can help me out of this problem

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using some wacky joins you can get a functional get max rows per category query.

What you essentially need to do is to join the table to itself and make sure that the joined values only contain the top values for the `CODESCHOOL` column.

I've also added a `:schoolname` parameter because you wanted to search by schoolname

Example:

```sql
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    TABLE1 A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 B ON B.NAME = A.NAME
        AND B.CODESCHOOL < A.CODESCHOOL
WHERE
    B.CODESCHOOL IS NULL AND
    (
        (A.SCHOOLNAME = :SCHOOLNAME AND :SCHOOLNAME IS NOT NULL) OR
        (:SCHOOLNAME IS NULL)
    );
```

this should create this output, note that dark has 2 outputs because it has 2 rows with the same code school which is the max in the dark "category"/name.

```
ID|NAME  |SCHOOLNAME      |CODESCHOOL
--| -----|----------------|----------
 4|Knight|LA Senior HS    |         2
 5|JOHN  |HARVARD         |         3
 2|DARK  |Kindergarten 111|         1
 1|DARK  |Kindergarten 123|         1
```

It's not the most effective query but it should be more than good enough as a starting point.

Sidenote: I've been blatantly stealing this logic for a while from https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/

Answer (score 0):

I am using an analytical window function ROW_NUMBER().
This will group (or partition) by NAME then select the top 1 CODESCHOOL in DESC order.

```
 Select NAME, 
   SCHOOLNAME, 
    CODESCHOOL
  From (
     Select NAME, 
     SCHOOLNAME, 
      CODESCHOOL,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY CODESCHOOL DESC) as rn
      from myTable)
  Where rn = 1;
```